# Как сделать всплывающие блоки с анимацией при скролле?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо сделать анимацию всплывания блоков, когда экран нижней частью доедет до блока, блок должен плавно выехать вверх при этом постепенно прозрачность уходит. 
Пример анимации есть на сайте [rolex](https://www.rolex.com/ru/watches/cosmograph-daytona/m116503-0004.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать следующую библиотеку:

> https://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW

Очень легко подключается. Достаточно добавить 2 файла + написать скрипт:

```
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>
```

И уже к нужному блоку прописать класс анимации.

Посмотреть виды анимаций можно здесь:

> https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/